# Contar 3 distintos estados de un campo en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente trozo de codigo de mysql

```
SELECT Pedidos.CodigoCliente, COUNT(Pedidos.Estado) FROM Pedidos
WHERE Pedidos.Estado = 'Pendiente'
GROUP BY CodigoPedido;
SELECT Pedidos.CodigoCliente, COUNT(Pedidos.Estado) FROM Pedidos
WHERE Pedidos.Estado = 'Rechazado'
GROUP BY CodigoPedido;
SELECT Pedidos.CodigoCliente, COUNT(Pedidos.Estado) FROM Pedidos
WHERE Pedidos.Estado = 'Entregado'
GROUP BY CodigoPedido;
```

Es un ejercicio el enunciado esta comentado en el codigo, pero mi codigo no da una salida correcta. No se como conseguir hacer esta consulta: "Sacar cuántos pedidos tiene cada cliente en cada estado" es decir si el cliente tiene 2 pedidos en estado entregado que aparezca el codigo del cliente y al lado los dos pedidos y en que estado estan no se como hacerlo con los 3 tipos de estado distintos os añado cual es la tabla sobre la que estoy trabajando:

```
CREATE TABLE Pedidos (

  CodigoPedido integer NOT NULL,

  FechaPedido date NOT NULL,

  FechaEsperada date NOT NULL,

  FechaEntrega date DEFAULT NULL,

  Estado varchar(15) NOT NULL,

  Comentarios text,

  CodigoCliente integer NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (CodigoPedido),

  CONSTRAINT Pedidos_Cliente FOREIGN KEY (CodigoCliente) REFERENCES Clientes (CodigoCliente)

) engine=innodb;
```

Comment: Ya describiste el resultado esperado ¿Podrías ejemplificarlo?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es realizar un `COUNT` para cada tipo de estado

```
SELECT Pedidos.CodigoCliente, 
COUNT(SELECT Pedidos.Estado FROM Pedidos WHERE Pedidos.Estado = 'Entregado'), 
COUNT(SELECT Pedidos.Estado FROM Pedidos WHERE Pedidos.Estado = 'Pendiente'),
COUNT(SELECT Pedidos.Estado FROM Pedidos WHERE Pedidos.Estado = 'Rechazado') 
FROM Pedidos
GROUP BY CodigoCliente
```

Otra posible solución, sería por ejemplo usar un **CASE WHEN**:

```
SELECT Pedidos.CodigoCliente, 
CASE WHEN (Pedidos.Estado = 'Entregado') THEN COUNT(*) AS Entregado, 
CASE WHEN (Pedidos.Estado = 'Pendiente') THEN COUNT(*) AS Pendiente, 
CASE WHEN (Pedidos.Estado = 'Rechazado') THEN COUNT(*) AS Rechazado
FROM Pedidos
GROUP BY CodigoCliente
```